# Facebook C# SDK list of friends orderby name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am wanting to order the list of Facebook friends returned by the Facebook C# SDK by last name. Using LINQ was the easiest way I was able to accomplish this, but I would like to know if there is an easier or more efficient method? I thought I would share this at a minimum since I could not find any other examples of it.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(FBToken.Value);
dynamic results = client.Get("me/friends?fields=id,name,picture");

var fbfsort = from dynamic friend in (IList<object>)results["data"] orderby friend.name ascending select friend;
foreach (var f in fbfsort) {
    //do something here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) like this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(FBToken.Value);
dynamic result = client.Get("fql", new
{
    q = "SELECT uid, name, pic_small from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name"
});

foreach (var item in result.data)
{
    // do something here...
}
```

Hope it helps!